# Gitlab pipeline broken after upgrade

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I have recently updated my gitlab runner to 16.4.1 and suddenly my pipeline stopped working. I have no clue what causes this state. Before this upgrade, everythign worked fine.

Pipeline is really simple- it just connects to server via SSH and runs script as specific user. I have tried to run this script as that user on the machine and it worked fine. Now it seems that Gitlab completely ignores script part of the pipeline. All variables are properly set and accesible.

```
my-pipeline:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$PROJECT_IDENTIFIER != null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - when: never
  before_script:
    - apk add --update --no-cache openssh
    - install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    - ssh-keyscan -H $SSH_HOST > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
    - echo "start"
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "bash /scripts/myScript.sh $PROJECT_IDENTIFIER && exit"
    - echo "stop"
  after_script:
    - rm -rf ~/.ssh
```

Output is like

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.4.1 (XXX) on docker-runner XXX, system ID: XXX
Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image alpine:latest ...
Pulling docker image alpine:latest ...
Using docker image XXX for alpine:latest with digest XXXX ...
Preparing environment
Running on runner XXX
Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in XXX
Checking out 46e2c9a7 as detached HEAD (ref is main)...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image XXX for alpine:latest with digest alpine@sha256:XXX ...
$ apk add --update --no-cache openssh
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.18/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/10) Installing openssh-keygen (9.3_p2-r0)
(2/10) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.4_p20230506-r0)
(3/10) Installing libncursesw (6.4_p20230506-r0)
(4/10) Installing libedit (20221030.3.1-r1)
(5/10) Installing openssh-client-common (9.3_p2-r0)
(6/10) Installing openssh-client-default (9.3_p2-r0)
(7/10) Installing openssh-sftp-server (9.3_p2-r0)
(8/10) Installing openssh-server-common (9.3_p2-r0)
(9/10) Installing openssh-server (9.3_p2-r0)
(10/10) Installing openssh (9.3_p2-r0)
Executing busybox-1.36.1-r2.trigger
OK: 14 MiB in 25 packages
$ install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
$ ssh-keyscan -H $SSH_HOST > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
Running after_script
Running after script...
$ rm -rf ~/.ssh
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Does anyone have a clue why my pipeline is not processing script part at all?

Comment: The exit code 1 at the end indicates a failure, so to rule out issue with `"ssh"`, can you remove the `"ssh"` command from the script section and try to see if the job succeeds and you are able to see the echo output?

Comment: @Raghu Hello, thanks for reaching me. When I´ve deleted the ssh script row (so only two echoes are present), result is the same. So it looks like script part of pipeline is not called at all

Comment: I would check the logs and config on your remote host you're running this script on. I just ran an alpine container locally, ran your commands verbating (but changing variables and the command to run after ssh'ing) and it worked for me. Another thing to try is to add the `-vvv` flag to ssh to see debugging information. Like @Raghu said, since it says "exit 1" it means it tried the commands in your script section but one of them failed with an exit code of 1.

Comment: Is your GitLab server version the same as your GitLab runner?

Comment: @AdamMarshall thanks for reaching me. I have tried many things like adding verbose, changing runner type (to direct shell), printing all variables (including printing .ssh private key if its present), running all commands with that user on the server directly, all worked as charm. Anyway I gave up after many hours of struggle and changed the script completely so its does not use these libraries.

Comment: @sytech Hi, thanks for reaching me, Its the latest gitlab runner version (available via apt-get update) against gitlab.com directly, so I guess so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of struggle I gave up and changed the pipeline completely. This is the version that works same as the above one. I hope it might help anyone who will face the same issue as me.

```
my-pipeline:
  stage: deploy
  rules:
    - if: '$PROJECT_IDENTIFIER != null && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web"'
      when: always
    - when: never
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache openssh-client bash
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY | base64 -d > id_rsa
    - chmod 700 id_rsa
    - mv id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  script:
    - ssh $SSH_USER@$SSH_HOST "bash /scripts/myScript.sh $PROJECT_IDENTIFIER"
  after_script:
    - rm -rf ~/.ssh
```